# sheaves and cosheaves

Tags: sheaf-theory

I am struggling hard to understand the pushforwards and pullbacks of cosheaves. Are they also cosheaves? And what are quasicoherent cosheaves? Is there anything like coquasicoherent cosheaves? Please tell me a good refernce on theses topics, if there is some.

Comment: What do you want to do with your cosheaves (aside from pulling them back and pushing them forward)?

Comment: What is a cosheaf?

Comment: All the possible operations that one can do with a sheaf. Like taking their external tensor product. How about the structural cosheaf? is it a cosheaf of corings?

So, I have a quasicoherent sheaf $A$ of algebras over a scheme $X$. That means it is essentially $\mathcal{O}_X$-modules.
The dual of $A$ is a cosheaf. Will this dual cosheaf be also quasicoherent? And will it be a quasicoherent cosheaf of coalgebras? I mean, will it be $\mathcal{O}_X$-comodules.

Please suggest some good literature on this if you know some!

Comment: Wait..."the dual of $A$ is a cosheaf"??

Comment: A cosheaf is a covariant functor defined on the open subsets of a space that satisfies a right exactness property (analogous to the left exactness satisfied by sheaves).  If you take the dual of a sheaf "objectwise" you get a cosheaf, and vice versa.

Comment: By the way, the "dual" of an equalizer is not necessarily a coequalizer, so the dual of a sheaf need not be a cosheaf. For example consider the structure sheaf of Spec(Z). If dual means Hom(-,Z) then the dual vanishes on every proper open subset.

Comment: If $\mathcal{A}$ is a sheaf of algebras over $\mathbb{K}$, then by the dual of $\mathcal{A}$, I mean $\mathcal{A}^∗:=\text{Hom}_{\mathbb{K}}(\mathcal{A},\mathbb{K})$, which I think is a coseaf!!! 

Comment: I don't understand. The dual of the tangent sheaf $T_X$
of an algebraic variety $X$ is the cotangent sheaf 
$T^*_X$, not the "tangent cosheaf" (whatever the latter could mean)... 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**edit:** I was assuming you wanted an equalizer sheaf property, but this is not the definition of cosheaf, see comments - the following has nothing to do with cosheaves then!

If by "cosheaf" you mean a covariant functor from the opens of a space to sets/groups/etc., you could look at Moerdijk/MacLane's ["Sheaves in Geometry and Logic"](http://books.google.com/books?id=SGwwDerbEowC&printsec=frontcover&dq=%2522Sheaves+in+Geometry+and+Logic%2522&source=bl&ots=WxeQEqB_CR&sig=OTsIE4Vr1EdkGyDrLbHGDHYo5Do&hl=en&ei=VAnDTOGKJsaYOoKT1YAM&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=2&ved=0CBoQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q&f=false) - there you can learn some general sheaf theory on sites, which includes the cosheaf case. In particular pushforward and pullback are transport along the the two functors comprising a "geometric morphism". The notion of quasicoherent (co)sheaf can maybe also be defined in this generality by saying that something should look locally like a pullback from the "base topos".

Sorry for the jargon, I didn't get from your question what exactly you are up to - just take a look at the book and see if it suits you.

Comment: Thanks Peter,
I want to learn all the operations that one can do with a sheaf. Like taking their external tensor product. How about the structural cosheaf? is it a cosheaf of corings? So, I have a quasicoherent sheaf $A$ of algebras over a scheme $X$. That means it is essentially $\mathcal{O}_X$-modules. The dual of $A$  is a cosheaf. Will this dual cosheaf be also quasicoherent? And will it be a quasicoherent cosheaf of coalgebras? I mean, will it be $\mathcal{O}_X$-comodules.

Comment: you could probably make something resembling quasicoherent if you understand what it means to localize a coalgebra or comodule(there are ways to do this) I don't know if it will be as efficient as the ordinary situation. You also have a cotensor product operation... I think for very general stuff like pushforward or pullback(not quasicoherent!) everything works fine if you just "op" the category of open sets and look at sheaves on that?

Comment: The descent conditions for sheaves and cosheaves are different.  I do not think that understanding cosheaves is simply a matter of passing to the opposite category in the manner you suggest.

Comment: Yes, I didn't suspect there was a coequalizer property defining a cosheaf - then the above source will not lead you anywhere!

Comment: Thanks everybody.
Daniel, Can you please elaborate a bit more on localizing a coalgebra or a comodule. Where can I read about this more?

Answer (score 11):

I've written a preprint about (what I call) contraherent cosheaves of modules over the structure sheaf of rings of a scheme -- http://arxiv.org/abs/1209.2995 .  These are a kind of dual creatures to quasi-coherent sheaves.  The preprint will be updated and expanded (eventually).

Comment: I can't decide if "Contraherent" is an ugly co-ification of "coherent", or if it is a really good pun.

Comment: The term was chosen because contraherent cosheaves stand in the same relationship to quasi-coherent sheaves as contramodules do to comodules over corings.  Also, "contraherent" seems to be a legitimate Latin word (with the meaning rather close to that of "coherent", as far as I can tell) -- http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/contraherent

Answer (score 6):

If you have the stomach for hard topos theory a good reference is

Singular coverings of toposes -- M. Bunge, J. Funk

The first chapter is probably enough to answer your question. The upshot is that if you have a site, then the category of cosheaves can be identified with the category of cocontinuous functors on the category of sheaves. This should give you a pretty good idea of what operations you can perform on cosheaves.

Btw, in this context, cosheaves are also called Lawvere distributions -- distributions because of the analogy with the Riesz representation theorem that identifies measures (cosheaves) with linear functionals (cocontinuous functors).

Hope it helps, regards,
G. Rodrigues

Comment: Many thanks Rodrigues.
What I am still thinking is how to define quasicoherent cosheaves! It seems that it is natural to think of them as cosheaves of $\mathcal{O}^\circ_X$-comodules. and call them quasicoherent if their dual sheaf is quasicoherent. What do you say?

Comment: @Neha: unfortunately, cannot help you with quasi-coherence. My knowledge about it resumes to knowing where I can find the definition if I ever need it.

Answer (score 2):

Look at Bredon's 'Sheaf Theory', Chapter Six: "Cosheaves and Cech Homology"

I am not aware of any quasi-coherent story.

Answer (score 2):

According to Skliarienko, the Borel-Moore homology (with coefficients in a sheaf) is badly "defective"; and the "right" homology should have coefficients in a co(pre)sheaf. (He makes this point in a few of his works; but most clearly in the editor's comments to the Russian translation of Bredon's "Sheaf theory".)

In fact, there exist [two](http://www.mathnet.ru/php/archive.phtml?wshow=paper&jrnid=sm&paperid=3030&option_lang=eng) [papers](http://www.mathnet.ru/php/archive.phtml?wshow=paper&jrnid=sm&paperid=3153&option_lang=eng) by Beniaminov which are precisely about this. I'm a bit puzzled that Skliarienko cited them with enthusiasm in early 1970s, but later ignored on several occasions when speaking of the desired cosheaf homology. There is also a followup paper by [Golovin](http://www.zentralblatt-math.org/zmath/en/advanced/?q=an%3A0576.55004&format=complete) which I haven't checked yet.